# FTP file upload - Destination folder path error

Tags: php

```
$name=$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
$filename=$_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"];

$ftp_server = "ftp.sitename.com";
$ftp_user_name = "ftpusername";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";
```

For LOCAL Apache Web Server

```
$destination_file = "/var/www/html/websitefolder/videoupload/";
```

For Actual Godaddy Apache Web Server

```
Try 1: $destination_file = "/public_html/videoupload/";
Try 2: $destination_file = "http://websitename.com/videoupload/";
Try 3: $destination_file = "./videoupload/";
Try 4: $destination_file = "/home/websitename/public_html/videoupload/";

$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file.$name, $filename, FTP_ASCII);
```

Above code works fine when I upload file on my local apache web server. But same code is not working on my actual godaddy hosting apache web server. It is giving below error...

```
Warning: ftp_put(): Can't open that file: No such file or directory in /home/websitename/public_html/videoupload/video_upload.php on line 41
```

So I guess destination path is wrong but not sure what will be correct path to right? Please let me know.

Comment: this upload php file is placed in root of your website?

Comment: if yes then you destination path should be like this


  `$destination_file = "videoupload/";`

Comment: When i connect through ftp as an account owner then i have only access to this "public_html" folder as a root. Please let me explain if there any example. Thank you.

Comment: if  you use this code then which error gives that tell me.
`$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, 'videoupload/'.$name, $filename, FTP_ASCII);`

Comment: I am getting same warning message that I have mentioned in my question and result is that file is not uploaded.

Comment: you have to get the right relative path using the echo 
 `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`
`$upload = ftp_put($conn_id,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/'.$name, $filename, FTP_ASCII);`

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']'returns this path /home/websitename/public_html/ and I already have mentioned it as I mentioned in my question

Comment: `$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]`may be returning blank, therefore the function `ftp_put` cannot place the file. Change the line `$name=$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];` to `$name="actual_filename.extension";` and try that. Additionally, the `$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];` needs to be reduced to only a filename as the path may be attached, use `basename($_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"])`

Comment: @pokeybit, I will try that but I am still confused about what should be proper destination path... can you please suggest something about it... local path is working fine but none of actual hosting server path are working...

Comment: if `/home/websitename/public_html/` is the result from your call to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` then `$destination_file = "/home/websitename/public_html/videoupload/";` is the correct destination path.

Comment: @pokeybit, yes i already tried that path as I mentioned in my question but not sure why this path is not working. And `$_FILES` is not returning blank value. For local apache web server this path `/var/www/html/websitefolder/videoupload/` is working perferctly

Comment: Tell me what `$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]` returns please?

Comment: @pokeybit, `$_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"]` is returning `chimp1.mpeg` (this is name of file that I am uploading). Where `$_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"]` is returning `/tmp/php8HBdO0`